# How get number of rows from peewee database?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-peewee

I only need to get the number of rows from the peewee database. I know that `.count` or `.wrapped_count` can be executed in a query.

```py
num_of_rows = Video.select().wrapped_count()
```

I need to execute a select query to get the number of rows. Does it affect performance and is there any method or field that I can use to get how many rows exist in the database?

In raw SQL query, I could write it like this.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM video;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Video.select().count()
```

Issues a `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM video` query.